# Multiple radio button per table row

Tags: angular, angular6

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Agenda No</th>
                        <th scope="col">Agenda Description</th>
                        <th scope="col">Opinion</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of agendaList">
                        <td>Agenda&nbsp;{{item.AGENDANO}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.AGENDA_DESC}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input type="radio" value="1" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Yes</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input type="radio" value="0" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">No</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I have table of 3 values. each row will have 2 radio button, "yes" or "no". How can I select one of them from each row individually.

Means:

1st row --> "yes", "no" ---> i will select yes

2nd row --> "yes", "no" ---> i will select no

3rd row --> "yes", "no" ---> i will select yes

[image]

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th scope="col">Agenda No</th>
          <th scope="col">Agenda Description</th>
          <th scope="col">Opinion</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of agendaList">
          <td>Agenda&nbsp;{{item.AGENDANO}}</td>
          <td>{{item.AGENDA_DESC}}</td>
          <td>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <input type="radio" value="1" id="{{item.AGENDANO}}" name="{{item.AGENDANO}}" class="custom-control-input">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{item.AGENDANO}}">Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <input type="radio" value="0" id="{{item.AGENDANO}}" name="{{item.AGENDANO}}" class="custom-control-input">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{item.AGENDANO}}">No</label>
              </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

check out [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjy1v5)

Do let me know if you have any doubt.

**updated**
attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: It's not working. It's only selecting "yes". If i click no it goes to yes.

Comment: I have attached screenshot, can you please check ?

Comment: my bad now it's working. maybe something wrong with my bootstrap. I removed the class="custom-control-input" from input. weird !!!!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwdean

U need to change their name attributes. Make unique them per each row forExample u can write like `name="customRadio{{item.AGENDANO}}"`
and create one more atttibute to bind  your answer to your model. I created example stackblitz demo for u

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Agenda No</th>
                        <th scope="col">Agenda Description</th>
                        <th scope="col">Opinion</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of agendaList">
                        <td>Agenda&nbsp;{{item.AGENDANO}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.AGENDA_DESC}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input type="radio" value="1" id="customRadio{{item.AGENDANO}}" name="customRadio{{item.AGENDANO}}" class="custom-control-input">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio{{item.AGENDANO}}">Yes</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input type="radio" value="0" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio{{item.AGENDANO}}" class="custom-control-input">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio{{item.AGENDANO}}">No</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```